# How to control QTextBrowser horizontal scroll bar

Tags: python, qtextbrowser

The code below create a single `QTextBrowser` widget filling it with the long lines of text. Since there was `view.setLineWrapMode(0)` applied the view does not wrap the text but places each line on a single line regardless of how long the line is. Notice that when the window is shown the horizontal scroll-bar is rewided all the way to the right: so we are seeing the end of the lines:

[image]

Instead I would like the textBrowser to set the horizontal scroll bar to the left so we could see the begining of the text line. Please see this image:

[image]

How to achieve this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

view = QtGui.QTextBrowser() 
for i in range(25):
    view.append(10*('Long Line of text # %004d '%i) )
view.setLineWrapMode(0)

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the Horizontal Scrollbar with `{your QTextBrowser}.horizontalScrollBar()`, then you have to place it in the initial position, that is, `{your Scrollbar}.setValue(0)`:

```
{your QTextBrowser}.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(0)
```

Complete Code:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
    for i in range(25):
        view.append(10*('Long Line of text # %004d '%i) )

    view.setLineWrapMode(QtGui.QTextBrowser.NoWrap)
    view.show()
    view.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(0)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: And what if I want to go to full bottom of the list ? setvalue(0) is Top... and then please?